# Is it possible to run a program in Windows XP Mode directly from a batch file that is in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, windows-xp-mode

I have Windows 7 Ultimate with [Windows XP Mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/windows-xp-mode) installed.

In my host OS (Windows 7) I have a batch file which executes some commands. I have to execute also three programs that are installed in my Windows XP Mode (Windows' debug.exe and two others programs). Is there a way to run them directly from my batch file?

Thank you!

Comment: From CMD you can start a desktop short-cut / program link in the `C:\Users` folder, though `start /wait` doesn't wait.

Comment: @AFH Which command do I have to use?

Comment: You can invoke the link, just like any `exe` file, eg `C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\DeskTopName.lnk`. You can pass parameters, provided you have allowed for them in the link run string. You can use `start`, but the `/wait` option waits until the program has been scheduled through the link, not until the target program ends.

Comment: I don't have XP Mode for testing, but couldn't you associate a task in Win 7 with running the XP program and set the task to run in compatibility mode, then put the task in your batch file?

Comment: @AFH Yes, but I can't copy a link from XP Mode to my Windows 7 PC, as the lnk file will point to a file that doesn't exist in my Windows 7 C drive

Comment: @fixer1234 The program is installed in the Windows XP Mode, and I don't know how to set a task to run it from the host OS.

Comment: This technique is used as a workaround for programs that require UAC authorization.  There are a lot of helpful links if you search on Windows, task, and UAC.  Here is one: http://www.7tutorials.com/use-task-scheduler-launch-programs-without-uac-prompts.  I don't have access to Windows right now, but one of the settings is to run the task in compatibility mode.  (You probably won't need the Run as Administrator setting.)

Comment: @fixer1234 Thanks for the suggestion, but in fact I don't need to run a program without UAC. I neet to run a 16-bit program that can't run on Windows 7 64 bit, but can in Windows XP Mode.

Comment: Right, the UAC purpose is just one application of the technique.  Defining a task is a way to run a program using different characteristics.  You can set a task to run in compatibility mode, which you can't do inside XP Mode.

Comment: If you put a link on your desktop or start menu (or anywhere else, for that matter), then you set compatibility mode for XP in the link properties. This is what I assumed you had been doing.

Comment: @AFH I don't neet to run it in compatibility mode, but on Windows XP Mode. You can find more information about it here: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/windows-xp-mode

Comment: OK, but if you want to call it from a batch file together with W7 native programs then I don't see how you can do it without using compatibility mode. If you want to call programs in a VM, then you will need to control the execution through command / flag files in a shared directory.

Comment: @AFH That's what I want. I need to do something with my file on Windows 7 and then to do some other things with some programs that are in Windows XP Mode. Is it possible? Or do I have to manually call a batch file in my Windows XP Mode every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cheap-and-cheerful approach to accomplish this is through a shared directory (which will probably have different paths in XP and W7, though you could use a drive letter for the share and make it the same on both). You can simply use the presence of command and response files to synchronise the execution on each system.

On XP you have a command shell running constantly with the core loop:-

```
:Loop
sleep 10
if not exist {XPshare}\XPcommand.cmd goto Loop
del {XPshare}\XPresponse.txt
call {XPshare}\XPcommand.cmd > {XPshare}\XPcommand.txt
ren {XPshare}\XPcommand.txt XPresponse.txt
del {XPshare}\XPcommand.cmd
goto Loop
```

You may want to add logging and otherwise refine the script. After the `call` command you could add `echo {unique string}Completion status = %errorlevel% >> {XPshare}\XPcommand.txt` and pick this up in the post-analysis.

Whenever you want to execute an XP command from W7, call a `cmd` script with the command passed in its parameters and containing:-

```
del {W7share}\XPresponse.txt
echo %* > {W7share}\XPcommand.cmd
:Loop
sleep 2
if exist {W7share}\XPcommand.cmd goto Loop
```

When you return from this, you can analyse `XPresponse.txt` and perform any post-processing. It is not strictly necessary to delete `XPresponse.txt`, but it just makes sure that no previous responses can confuse any W7 checks.

There are innumerable versions of `sleep.exe`, which suspends for a number of seconds, including two from MS, in *Services for Unix* and in *Windows Resource Kit*. The number of seconds to choose is a balance between responsiveness and polling overhead. I have suggested a shorter interval on W7, because the polling is done only while the XP command is executing, while on XP it is done at all other times.